# Cannot input into textbox using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to input into a text box some values for this website using selenium however it is not working. The code is executing with no errors. Can someone please explain what I'm missing.

```
> from selenium import webdriver 
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
> import re, time, csv
> 
> 
> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
> 
> driver.get("https://www.ebs.ncrs.nhs.uk/pabs/login") driver.switch_to
> driver.maximize_window time.sleep(10)
> 
> username = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ubrn']")
> username.click() username.send_keys("000200020002")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I don't see any major errors in your code block. You may consider to omit `driver.switch_to` as there the element with `xpath` ".//*[@id='ubrn']" is on the top window. Consider avoiding `time.sleep(n)` and replace with `implicitly_wait` or `Explicit Wait`:

Here is your own code block with some simple tweaks which works fine at my end:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import re, time, csv

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.ebs.ncrs.nhs.uk/pabs/login")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ubrn']")
username.click()
username.send_keys("000200020002")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Wow fantastic it worked, how did it work?
What was wrong with my code?

Thank you again

Comment: @M.Ustun Glad to be able to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

username.clear();
username.sendkeys("12335");